# Get second last message with Discord.Js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to get the second last message sent in the same channel where it was sent, but when i use `.fetchMessages` with limit of two messages and try to get the second one, it doesn't work.

I tried with this

```
channel.fetchMessages({limit:2}).then(res =>{
 let lm = res[1]
 console.log(lm)
})
```

But it doesn't works

Comment: Post code so someone can try to help you.

Answer (score 4):

[`channel.fetchMessages()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=fetchMessages) returns a [Collection](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Collection) of messages, which is an extended class of [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map). They can not be iterated over like `res[1]`, instead you can do one of the two things.

#### 1.Using `.last()` - [ref](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Collection?scrollTo=last)

This will get you the last element from the collection, which is the 2nd last message.

```
channel.fetchMessages({limit: 2}).then(res => {
 let lm = res.last()
 console.log(lm)
})
```

#### 2.Using `.array()` - [ref](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Collection?scrollTo=array)

This will convert the Collection to an array which can be iterated over.

```
channel.fetchMessages({limit: 2}).then(res => {
 let lm = res.array()[1]
 console.log(lm)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

In v12, `channel.fetchMessages` does not work anymore instead it's `channel.messages.fetch`

^ [Reference](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v12.html#fetch)

So updating tintin9999's answer the two solutions will be:

**1. Using `.last()`**

```
channel.messages.fetch({limit: 2}).then(res => {
let lm = res.last()
console.log(lm)
})
```

**2. Using `.array()`**

```
channel.messages.fetch({limit: 2}).then(res => {
 let lm = res.array()[1]
 console.log(lm)
})
```